# Resourse leak: 'salida' is never closed

Tags: java

cuando quiero correr mi programa no me deja por este error y no se solucionarlo alguien tiene idea y me pueda ayudar con consejos

```js
try {
  fout = new FileOutputStream("Video.txt");
  ObjectOutputStream salida = new ObjectOutputStream(fout); //aqui marca el error
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    salida.writeObject(v1[cont]);
  }
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Informacion almacenada con éxito en archivo");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontro el archivo");
} catch (IOException ex) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error E/S");
} finally {
  try {
    fout.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerar el archivo");
  }
}
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es muy claro: tienes que cerrar `salida` cuando termines de trabajar con ese recurso, cosa que no estás haciendo. OJO, es `salida` lo que debes cerrar, y haciendo eso cerrarás también a `fout`, por tanto, esto ya no será necesario: `fout.close()`. Para más detalles, revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4092914/5587982).

Comment: Si se te olvida cerrar los streams, deberías intentar con ***try-withresources***, son de mucha ayuda

Comment: try con recursos++, aunque podrías simplemente cerrar salida en el finally